# Oracle group by function

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by

I have a table as shown below and in the PRICE_VOLUME_COST_INDICATOR column, there are three distinct values namely

1. COST
2. PRICE
3. VOLUME

[image: Table structure]

And  I want to perform

```
SELECT PRICE_VOLUME_COST_INDICATOR,
       SUM(AMOUNT) 
FROM MY_TABLE 
GROUP BY PRICE_VOLUME_COST_INDICATOR
```

but I don't want "PRICE" record to be grouped. For "PRICE" records alone I want any amount value.

I am expecting the output below:

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify this output? Are you only returning one "price" record because both of them have the same amount of 36.15?

Comment: For all the "Price" records , amount will be same. I want to return one record

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Sure @ a_horse_with_no_name , I will keep that in mind while posting questions next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, according to the comment, all the "price" records have the same amount, you could use the aggregate `max` (or `min`) to just get one of them, and a `case` expression to choose between `max` and `sum` depending on the price_volume_cost_indicator:

```
SELECT   price_volume_cost_indicator, 
         CASE price_volume_cost_indicator WHEN 'PRICE' THEN MAX(amount)
                                          ELSE SUM(amount)
         END
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY price_volume_cost_indicator
```